# moving bootstrap glyphicon inside row div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been asked to do some maintenance on a site, specifically to add a '?' icon next to a textbox so it can give hints to the user on the formatting of text inside the box etc etc:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <!-- ngIf: icon != '' && !isFaIcon --><span ng-if="icon != '' &amp;&amp; !isFaIcon" class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-tag icon-inline btn-item">

  </span><!-- end ngIf: icon != '' && !isFaIcon -->

  <!-- ngIf: icon != '' && isFaIcon -->

  <input type="text" class="form-control btn-item form-tab-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" placeholder="Target URL" ng-model="model">

  <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk input-state"></span>

  <span class="help input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign input-state"></span>
</div>
```

The final span is the line I added, and altogether it looks like this:

[image: this]

My question is, how can I move that question mark icon 20 pixels or so to the right, so there is a gap between the asterix icon and the question mark? I've tried messing around with 'padding-left' in the .help css but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question mark icon has only this "box" design, because it has `padding: 6px 12px;`. So if you reduce the `padding-left`, you can increase `padding-right` by the same amount and have it look like it moved to the left.

Currently: `padding-left/right: 12px;`
If we now reduce `padding-left` by `6px` and add it to `padding-right`, it will look more left aligned.

```
.help {
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 18px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4okgot5/1/

You also could let it the same way and just increase the `padding-right`, so the box will look a bit bigger, but it's more left aligned than right.

```
.help {
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 24px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4okgot5/2/

---

**EDIT**

Because the question has changed, I leave my edit here for the real wanted answer.

Try adding another `span`-Element there and just adjust the `padding-left` like following:

**HTML**

```
<span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk input-state"></span>

<span class="gap input-group-addon glyphicon input-state"></span>

<span class="help input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign input-state"></span>
```

**CSS**

```
.gap  {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4okgot5/3/

The `25px` is just an example. Adjust it to your space you want to have between the icons.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I meant move it to the right.. I'll edit my original question, I'm so stupid. But what I meant was moving the box containing the question mark 20 or so pixels to the right, so there is a gap between the asterix box and the question mark box. Do you know how to do that? Thanks for your answer anyway!